# JSoup Screen Scraping With Many Divs

Tags: android, jsoup

I have a page I want to scrape with android, and the contents are want are located like this:

```
body
div#wrapper
div#mainContentArea
div#scheduleModule
div#scheduleDayView
div#scheduleDayViewScroll 
div#scheduleItemContainer
div#eventContainer
div#SSPP_o090570*A*
div.eventInfo
p.eventText
span.eventInfoDefault
```

How can I access the span using jsoup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to be taken out in the streets and whipped for your transgressions, you will split up that block of text there.

Anyway, you want to find the span whose class is eventInfoDefault? Well:

```
Document site = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com");
Element span = site.select("span.eventInfoDefault").first();
//Proceed to do whatever you want with that below.
```

Source: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax